# should i set variable to null when user exits

Tags: java

I'm creating a text based game to further my knowledge with java.

The user uses their keyboard to interact with the game, and while in the main menu can press "2" to quit the game.

```
if(userInput.equals("2")){
            playing = false;
```

The `playing` variable defines whether the game loop should continue running or not.

I also have a variable named `mode` which defines which state the game is in, for example, the main menu, options, or the actual game.

Should i change `mode` to `"null"` (or similar) when i set `playing = false`?

I't doesn't matter very much to my overall program, but since I am new to java i would like to know what the best practices are for these kinds of things.

Comment: If you do not need it more -- yes.

Comment: Hard to tell without more context.  If `mode` is a local variable, though, setting it to `null` does not accomplish anything if `mode` will soon go "out of scope"--e.g. the method that declares `mode` exits so that `mode` is no longer accessible.

Comment: This isn't really opinion based - either it *is* required in order to allow garbage collection to take place, or it isn't. More context would help, but the question can still have a reasonable answer anyway.

Comment: @ajb - If the method is big and continuously producing objects, then it makes sense to set them to null. right?. suppose I have 2 for loops producing objects one below another, and adding them to 2 different arraylists, then once the first loop is done and if its objects are no longer needed, setting the arraylist to null / clearing it would be a really good option. Even if they are all local variables.

Comment: @TheLostMind Assuming your `ArrayList` is a local variable, I think it can be a good idea to set it to `null` if it won't be needed any more, but will still be in scope through a longish calculation (your second loop).  My comment pertained to the case where someone is thinking of setting a local variable to `null` just before the method returns; this isn't necessary.  In your case, putting the local variable in a block might be a good idea ... `{ ArrayList<T> list; [first loop] } [second loop]` but I'm not 100% certain that `list` becomes eligible for GC at the `}`.

Comment: @ajb - *someone is thinking of setting a local variable to null just before the method returns; this isn't necessary* - I completely agree :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *pressing* 2 closes the program (shutting down the JVM), then it doesn't make much of a difference. Actually you will have an additional instruction to push the null reference onto the stack.

If you have quite a lot of code (the term *lot* is *relative*), then you can set the reference to `null` so as to tell the gc (when the next GC cycle runs) that you no longer need the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need it more -- yes.
But I think better way is hold all data belong to player in one class. And release reference to object of this class (set to null) when user left your program.